# Silverlight DataGrid set cell IsReadOnly programmatically

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, binding

I am binding a data grid to a collection of Task objects. A particular column needs some special rules pertaining to editing:

```
<!--Percent Complete-->
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="%" 
                         ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}" 
                         Binding="{Binding PercentComplete, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource PercentConverter}}" />
```

What I want to do is set the IsReadOnly property only for each task's percent complete cell based on a property on the actual Task object. I've tried this:

```
<!--Percent Complete-->
<data:DataGridTextColumn Header="%" 
                         ElementStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignStyle}" 
                         Binding="{Binding PercentComplete, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource PercentConverter}}"
                         IsReadOnly={Binding IsNotLocalID} />
```

but apparently you can't bind to the IsReadOnly property on a data grid column. What is the best way do to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can Bind directly to this.  I have found this extended DataGrid for Silverlight which will do the trick though.

[Extended DataGrid](http://agdatagridext.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [DataGridColumn.IsReadOnly Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.isreadonly(v=VS.100).aspx) is a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=VS.100).aspx) so it should be bindable. Change your XAML to `IsReadOnly="{Binding IsNotLocalID}"` (Note the added quotes) and see what happens. Are you getting any binding failures in the Visual Studio output window?

Comment: Ah, I'm on Silverlight 3, not Silverlight 4.

Comment: DataGrid is quite an old codebase as Silverlight goes, and many of its properties are not dependency properties. In particular, IsReadOnly on the DataGridBoundColumn base class is not a dependency property. I have this on good authority from the program manager for DataGrid. I've also directly asked him when the codebase will be updated and he declined to comment.

Comment: Peter, I am exactly having the same problem. IsReadOnly is definitely not a dependencyproperty.  I am trying to create my own as a workaround and still don't get it working. Do you have a working example for this? Thanks